# Neither pytype nor mypy is complaining about type error?

Tags: python

I have the following test script which fails by design. However, neither pytype nor mypy warned me about the problem. Why does this happens?

```
import pandas as pd
import collections


def junkmerge(dfs: collections.abc.Sequence, *args, **kwargs) -> pd.DataFrame:
    print(dfs)
    return pd.concat(dfs, *args, **kwargs)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pd1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'a': [1]})
    pd2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'a': [2]})
    junkmerge(pd1, pd2, join='outer')
```

NOTE: I specifically checked that dataframe is not a sequence.

```
In [6]: isinstance(pd1, collections.abc.Sequence)                      
Out[6]: False

In [10]: issubclass(pd.DataFrame, collections.abc.Sequence)                                                                                                                                                        
Out[10]: False
```

Comment: elaborate what *fails by design* means?

Comment: Assuming `DataFrame` is registered as a (virtual) subclass of `Sequence`, there are no type errors in this code to be reported.

Comment: @chepner I specifically checked that DataFrame is not a sequence.

Comment: @chepner check the note I added to the question.

Comment: `mypy` may be checking more explicitly (as a `DataFrame` certainly *qualifies* as a subclass of `Sequence`, having the necessary methods. I think.).

Comment: Considering Python's duck typing, `isinstance(x, t)` returning `False` doesn't mean `x` cannot _be used_ where a `t` is expected.

Comment: @Gabriel issubclass should handle it. Check the __subclasshook__ method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither mypy not pytype supports pandas. So when a dataframe is passed in as a function arguments, neither performs a check.

After removing the pandas dependency in the code, i was able to get the error from both mypy and pytype.

See code copied below.

```
import collections

def junkmerge(dfs: collections.abc.Sequence[int], *args, **kwargs) -> pd.DataFrame:
    print(dfs)
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    junkmerge(1, 2, join='outer')
```